# Cannot set an object to null inside a method

Tags: c#

In the below code I am trying to set node to null in test method. When I do that the node becomes Null only inside the scope of the method, but 'parent'  doesn't become null. My understanding was objects are passed to methods as reference and can be directly manipulated inside the method. I think there is something wrong in my conceptual understanding. Can you explain why assigning the node to null doesn't assign parent to null.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Node parent = new Node();
        parent.key = 50;
        parent.left = new Node();
        Test.test(parent);
    }
}

class Test
 {
    public static void test(Node node)
    {
       node.key = 1111;
       node = null;
    }
 }

class Node
    {
        public object key { get; set; }
        public Node left = null;
        public Node right = null;
    }
```

Comment: You are passing *node* by value (ie passing in a copy of it's *handle*), and need to pass it by reference (ie as the original *handle*). Link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f1hz171.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your response. In that case how does the field values change.? Example  when i assign node.key = 1111, parent.key also changes to 1111.

Comment: Note that the preferred means of returning values from a method is as the return value of a function or property, not as a ref* or *out* parameter as you are attempting here. Of course, there are always exceptions.

Comment: See my edit to the first comment. Don't confuse the object itself with its *handle* (or *reference*, or if you must *pointer*).

Comment: I recommend that you read Jon Skeet's article on the subject: http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/parameters.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because parameters are passed by value, so in your test method, a copy of parent variable has been created, you are just setting the copy of variable to null. Though you still can manipulate the object because the copy variable is pointing to the object in the heap.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        SetNull(foo);

        Console.WriteLine(foo.ID);// print 2
    }

    private static void SetNull(Foo foo)
    {
        foo.ID = 2;
        foo = null;
    }
}


class Foo
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You're not actually passing `parent` to `node` by reference here. This means a value of `parent` is being copied to `node` in the `test` function. In this case, that value simply points to a `Node` object.

`node.key = 1111` works as you expect because it uses that value to access the same object which `parent` is also pointing to. i.e. both `node` and `parent` contain values pointing to the same locations in memory. As such, both can observe the modification.

However when you say `node = null`, you're assigning a new value to the `node` variable inside the `test` function. This means you're changing the pointer stored as the value in that particular variable to `null`, which in no way modifies the value for `parent` - that's still pointing to the `Node` object.

Mind my amateur ASCII art, but I think it's kind of like this:

```
    Test.test(parent);       

         <node object>
           ^       ^ 
           .           .
           .               .
           .                   .
    +------.----+                   .  +-----------+
    |      .    |                       .          |
    |      .    |    (-> copied to)    |    .      |
    |  parent   |                      |    node   |
    +-----------+                      +-----------+
    Program.Main scope                 Test.test scope


    node = null;       

         <node object>
           ^ 
           .
           .
           .
    +------.----+                      +-----------+
    |      .    |                      |           |
    |      .    |                      |           |
    |  parent   |                      | node=null |
    +-----------+                      +-----------+
    Program.Main scope                 Test.test scope
```

Whereas if you happened to use `public static void test(ref Node node)` you could think of it more like this:

```
    Test.test(parent);       

         <node object>
           ^ 
           .
           .
           .
    +------.----+                      +-----------+
    |  parent <============================ node   |
    |           |                      |           |
    |           |                      |           |
    +-----------+                      +-----------+
    Program.Main scope                 Test.test scope


    node = null;       

         <node object>
            Lonely


    +-----------+                      +-----------+
    |  parent <============================ node   |
    |     =     |                      |           |
    |    null   |                      |           |
    +-----------+                      +-----------+
    Program.Main scope                 Test.test scope
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, a reference-to-`node` is being passed by-value (as `class` instances are Reference-types), as opposed to `node` itself being passed-by-value (if would be if it were a `struct`).

Comment: great ascii representation skills!

Answer (score 3):

Use the `ref` keyword:

```
public static void Test(ref Node node) {
    node = null;
}

// Usage

Node parent = ...
Test( ref parent );
Assert( parent == null );
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite this method here with a different variable name for the purpose of example:

```
public static void test(Node PassedNode)
    {
       PassedNode.key = 1111;
       PassedNode = null;
    }
```

`PassedNode` inside the `test` method points to the `Node parent = new Node();` object that was initially passed in and so when you modify the values of the properties of `PassedNode` inside the `test` method, then these changes will affect the object in the Main method because there's only one object. When you write `PassedNode = null` then `PassedNode` in the `test` method doesn't point to the original object anymore and that's all that happens: the object itself still lives on. If you want to clear the original reference, then you need to do that in the calling method.