# Reference Type passed by ref and without ref

Tags: c#

I am getting different result while calling 4 methods in different ways:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   var emp = new Employee { Name = "ABC" };

   ChangeName1(emp);
   Console.WriteLine(emp.Name); //XYZ

   ChangeName2(ref emp);
   Console.WriteLine(emp.Name); //XYZ

   ChangeToNull1(emp);
   Console.WriteLine(emp.Name); // XYZ

   ChangeToNull2(ref emp);
   Console.WriteLine(emp.Name); // Null Reference Exception

   Console.ReadLine();
}

static void ChangeName1(Employee e)
{
   e.Name = "XYZ";
}
static void ChangeName2(ref Employee e)
{
   e.Name = "XYZ";
}
static void ChangeToNull1(Employee e)
{
   e = null;
}
static void ChangeToNull2(ref Employee e)
{
   e = null;
}
```

As you can see the first 2 methods, I am changing the value of `Name` property and after returning from the method, the original object property is changed.

But when set the object to `null`, `ChangeToNull1` method doesn't change the original object but `ChangeToNull2` method does.

So my questions are:

**1.** Why C# behaving this way ?

**2.** Does C# makes a copy of original object while get passed to a method ?

**3.** If does then how it changes the original object properties like `Name`, and why not it changes the original object ?

**4.** Does c# copies original object while passed by `ref` ?

Comment: The problem is that you are handing in a Reference to a object in memory via call by value and call by reference. Stuff becomes wierd. Also note: Do not try to learn class behavior with String! It does not behave anything like the normal Reference Types. It is designed to work more like a primitive value type like lint.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30585483/cannot-set-an-object-to-null-inside-a-method maybe this explanation help you.

Comment: @Christopher Can you explain when `string` behaves differently than other types? I didn't encouter such a situation yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C#, there are two catgories of objects: Value-Types and Reference-Types.

Value-Types are `struct`s and `enum`s, such as `int` (`System.Int32`). These types always copied when they're passed. If you change an `int` in a method, the variable inside the caller won't change.

You are talking about reference types - classes, arrays and interfaces, basically.

In reference types, such as `string` (`System.String`), there are two sections: the object, and the pointer. For example, let's see your `Employee`. Suppose I declared a variable named `e1` of type `Employee`, and assigned to it's name `"abc"`:

```
Employee e1 = new Employee { Name = "abc" };
```

Now, there is an employee object in the memory (the heap, because reference types almost always are allocated in the heap, expect `stackalloc`), which contains `Name="abc"`. There is also (in the stack) a **pointer** to this object. Let's suppose we have this memory image:

```
 0x123 - An employee object          0x45F - the variable `e1` - pointer to the employee
|-------------------------|         |------------------|
|     Name = "abc"        |         |     0x123        |
|-------------------------|         |------------------|
```

When you pass it without `ref`, **the value of `e1` - `0x123`** is copied, but the employee isn't copied! So, if you change its name, the original employee *will* be changed! But if you change the pointer nothing will happen, since the pointer `e1` is just **copied**!

When you pass with `ref`, **the address of the pointer** is copied - `0x45F`. So, if you change the parameter, it *will* change `e1`, since it was not copied, but its address.

#### Edit:

If I assign a reference type variable to an another variable, for example:

```
var e1 = new Employee { Name = "abc" };
Employee e2 = employee;
```

then, `e2` is the same as `e1` - it'a also a pointer, which points to the same address. If we takes the prevoius memory image, now there is in the address `0x4AC` a variable named `e2`, contains also `0x123`, the address of the object. So, if we'll change `e2.Name`:

```
e2.Name = "new";
```

then, `e1.Name` is now `"new"`, too.
Last important fact about reference types, is that comparing (`==`) reference types (I'm talking when there is not an overloaded operator `==`), won't check if they contains the same values, but if they points to the same object. Let's see an example:

```
var e1 = new Employee { Name = "abc" };
Employee e2 = e1;
var e3 = new Employee { Name = "abc" };
var e4 = new Employee { Name = "123" };

Console.WriteLine(e1 == e4); // false
Console.WriteLine(e1 == e3); // false, since they don't point to the same object, they just contain the same values
Console.WriteLine(e1 == e2); // true, since they point to the same object
```

**Some comments about strings:**

1. Althought the class `System.String` is a reference type, it overloads `operator ==()`, so comparing two strings will give a correct result.
2. The compiler usually optimize strings, so if `string s1 = "abc";` and `string s2 = "abc";`, `s1` and `s2` can point to the same address (for memory saving). It's possible because strings are immutable - if, for example, you call `Replace()` on a string, it'll create a new string. So you shouldn't know about this (but it's important if you write unsafe code).

Comment: can I set object to null ? because the reference if I set to null,it becomes null but it does not change the instance to null.

Comment: @BimalDas Yes, when you set a reference to null, you don't delete the object from the memory, but now, there are not more references to it, and so, in the next time the GC will run, it will find that this object has no references, and it will delete it (it's a very complex process, I explained it simply, but until object is destroyed, this are some stations.)

Answer (score 2):

It behaves that way because C# passes a copy of the value of the pointer to the reference type. That's a bit of a mouthful, so this might be more revealing:

When you write:

```
var emp = new Employee { Name = "ABC" };
```

You're creating an instance of `Employee` and storing the *pointer* to that object in the variable `emp`. 
Let's assume the memory location of `emp` is `0x000001`. And the *value* of that (the location of the object) is `0x0000AA`.

When you call:

```
ChangeName1(emp);
```

You're passing the value `0x0000AA`. Within the method `ChangeName1`, the value of `e` is `0x0000AA`, but *it's* location is not `0x000001`. It's stored in a different place in memory.

However, when you call:

```
ChangeName2(ref emp);
```

You're passing the memory location of `emp`, which is `0x000001`. So within this method, updating `e` also updates `emp`.

---

To address the members - as noted above, you're not copying the object. Both `ChangeName1` and `ChangeName2` refer to the same object. They both refer to the object stored at `0x0000AA`.

---

For futher reading, see [When is a C# value/object copied and when is its reference copied?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347902/when-is-a-c-sharp-value-object-copied-and-when-is-its-reference-copied)

Answer (score 1):

```
static void ChangeName1(Employee e)
{
   e.Name = "XYZ";
}
```

Here, the new pointer "e" points to the Same object "emp" - so changes reflect.

```
static void ChangeName2(ref Employee e)
{
   e.Name = "XYZ";
}
```

Here "emp" is passed as reference - just that its named e. (easy to understand this way)

```
static void ChangeToNull1(Employee e)
{
   e = null;
}
```

Here, the new pointer "e" points to the Same object "emp" - When you set e= Null. the new pointer is null'd. Not the original object.

```
static void ChangeToNull2(ref Employee e)
{
   e = null;
}
```

I guess by now you understood whats going on.

Answer (score 1):

What "emp" is, is a reference variable. A variable that points to a instance of a reference type.

The ways reference variables works, are similar to how Pointers work. Naked pointers are a very fundamental tool of programming, but handling them is scarily dangerous. So the .NET team choose not to force you to handle them by default. But as they are so important, a lot of things had to be invented to repalce them (References and Delegates are jsut 2 common ones).

The object in memory and the (number) of references you hold to it are entirely unrealted. An object in memory can have 0, 1 or many references point at it. A object without any references will be collected by the GC, whenever it chooses to run next.

Setting a reference to null does not force a collection, it meerely makes the collection possible. A a high propabiltiy, given more runtime. But never a guarantee.